# Opening an overlay window after n seconds have passed of page being loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My client would like a page on their site to display a pop-up/overlay form a couple of seconds after the page they want it to appear on has finished loading. Being a complete novice when it comes to jQuery and javascript, could someone help me out please? I imagine it should be simple when you know how.

Answer (score 1):

This should help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        // here your stuff to display popup
    }, 30 * 1000); // 30 is number of seconds after page load
});
```